# adding a proxy support to specific perl module

Tags: perl, cpan

I am using the following Perl module from CPAN **Net::Whois::IANA**  which works well when there are no proxy but when a proxy is needed it fails .

from inspecting its code it using this module **IO::Socket::INET** to connect .
could someone provide how can I add proxy capability to this module ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a proxy for all protocols. A proxy is a protocol specific thing and there are different proxies needed for HTTP, SIP etc. As far as I know there is no such thing as a proxy defined for the whois protocol. What kind of proxy do you want to use with whois?

Comment: Thanks for the answer i totaly agree with you but I want to to forward my request to port 43 on internal service which do whois job for me and return the result back to me

Comment: So it is not a proxy, but you want to use your own server. According to the documentation of the module you should use -mywhois parameter in whois_query, according to the source code it might by -mywhois => {   myserver => [ hostname, port, timeout, \&query_method ]} where port, timeout and query_method are optional